# How do I set color table ranges in a Paraview python script?

Tags: python, paraview

I'm visualizing a time series of spatial data in Paraview, and I would like for my setup script to set the color tables for a given field based on the field's range over the full time series, rather than an individual snapshot. I've tried initializing the lookup table with values computed by the script, but to no avail.

The figure below shows results of running my setup script. The values in the Python Shell window are what the scales should be set to, but the color bar shows another value.

[image: results of running the setup script. The values in the Python Shell window are what the scales should be set to, but the color bar shows another value]

The relevant part of my setup script is here.

```
# get the scales for the surface fields
mag_os_xdmf = FindSource('mag_os.xdmf')
with h5py.File(mag_os_xdmf.FileName.replace('xdmf', 'h5'), 'r') as h5:
    for comp in ('br', 'bt', 'bp'):
        scale = np.abs(h5[comp].value).max()
        print(comp, scale)
        ctab = [-scale, 0.23137254901960785, 0.2980392156862745, 0.7529411764705882,
                scale, 0.7058823529411765, 0.01568627450980392, 0.14901960784313725]
        DataRep = GetDisplayProperties(mag_os_xdmf)
        lut = GetLookupTableForArray(comp, 1, NanColor=[0.24705882352941178, 0.0, 0.0],
                                     RGBPoints = ctab, ColorSpace='Diverging' )
        DataRep.ColorArrayName = ('POINT_DATA', comp)
        DataRep.LookupTable = lut
Render()
```

For comparison, here's the output of a python trace when I manually change the colorbar

```
try: paraview.simple
except: from paraview.simple import *
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

mag_os_xdmf = GetActiveSource()
DataRepresentation6 = GetDisplayProperties(mag_os_xdmf)
a1_br_PVLookupTable = GetLookupTableForArray( "br", 1, RGBPoints=[-0.122, 0.23, 0.299, 0.754, 0.122, 0.706, 0.016, 0.15] )

DataRepresentation6.ScalarOpacityFunction = []
DataRepresentation6.ColorArrayName = ('POINT_DATA', 'br')
DataRepresentation6.LookupTable = a1_br_PVLookupTable

Render()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
# get color transfer function/color map for 'br'
lut = GetColorTransferFunction('br')

# get opacity transfer function/opacity map for 'br'
opacityLut = GetOpacityTransferFunction('br')

# Rescale transfer function
lut.RescaleTransferFunction(-scale, scale)

# Rescale transfer function
opacityLut.RescaleTransferFunction(-scale, scale)
```

Comment: Which version of Paraview are you working with? Paraview 4.0.1 doesn't have those functions in paraview.simple. Paraview 5.0.1 and 4.4 both segfault when I try to load the XDMF files.

Comment: I work with the latest development version. Have you mailed the paraview mailing list or filed a bug report about the XDMF files causing crashes? I suggest that rather than trying to make it work in a now old version of ParaView.

Comment: I have now, we'll see if it's a problem with my files or with the program itself.